# What statistical test is best to compare ratios within each groups

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

I am doing a a/b test. I am interested in finding difference in ratio of revenue after the campaign vs before for both the groups. Both groups are random split from same population subjected to two marketing actions to be tested, which one works best.

```
example 
treatment group A : 1 week revenue after campaign 110 $
         1 week revenue before campaign 100 $
         total user count = 500
         ratio = 110/100 = 110%

treatment group B: 1 week revenue after campaign 240 $
     1 week revenue before campaign 200 $
         total user count = 800
         ratio = 240/200 = 120%
```

I am interested in understanding if the difference in ratio is significant between two groups at 95% CI.

What is the best statistical test i can use here ?

Comment: would you please indicate more information about relateness or independence of groupings ? please illustrate your data .

Comment: Which statistical test(s) do you propose and why ? it is very intituive to  respond with ifs and buts.

Comment: I updated my questions, let's say i am comparing control vs treatment group.

option 1.  Z test for proportion to compare the ratios.
          But, as per my understanding, proportion test is not suitable in this case.
option 2. If i am testing difference in revenue from test to control i would do mean comparison using Z test. 
Can i follow the same approach to compare the mean of ratios?

Comment: There seems to be a difficulty in terming one as a treatment group and another as control group. Both groups are being  subjected tocampaign !

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am sorry about the confusion.
my actual experimental setup is bit complicated. I am trying to make it simple here for illustrative purpose. I have a/b/c random split groups from same population group A and group B will be subjected to two different marketing templates to be tested.
in my example above let's keep control aside and look at two treatment groups and compare it. please let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: keeping aside control groupings should change the data from ratio to absolute ? Your interest is testing the difference or differece in ratios ?

Comment: difference in ratios. ratio of revenue post to revenue pre for treatment A vs treatment B

Comment: what about total user count  Are these treatment groups independent ?

Comment: yes. i intentionally kept different number of users in this example. it won't always be 50-50 split, sometimes we will do uneven split like 75 - 25 and so on. just wanted to account for different sample size in the calculation.
in this case treatment A is treated to 500 users and B is treated to 800 users. it is just an example. in actual test we do proper power calculation and carefully take number of samples. this example is just for my understanding.

Comment: I would take the LOG of ratios, and do a t-test on the transformed data:
https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_paired_or_ratio_t_test.htm